# Error when starting Gunicorn as nobody

Tags: django, virtualenv, gunicorn

So when I run the command

```
gunicorn test.wsgi:application --bind 127.0.0.1:8000 --workers=3 --user=nobody
```

I get the error:

```
OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/wgunicorn-QGaR6q'
```

Which seems like I'm not allowed to start the process as another user, so when I try the same command with sudo, I get a bunch of errors dealing with:

```
ImportError: No module named django.core.wsgi
```

and

```
raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)
gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>
```

I'm doing all this in a virtual environment so I'm thinking it has to do with it not recognizing it when I'm in sudo, but without sudo I don't have the permissions to start the server as another user.

Comment: Check permissions for the `/tmp` directory on your system...

Comment: Permissions allows everyone write/execute/read access. I looked more into it, and quite a few people are having the same problem as me following this guide for creating a django project on digital ocean droplets.

Answer (score 3):

I had this same issue if you edit your supervisor's app conf or run the command without the --user flag it works. I am also working with a digital ocean droplet and have not been able to get supervisor working with the user flag.

Comment: Don't you need the --user flag to set the user as nobody?

Comment: Well I am using supervisor to run a gunicorn script I wrote. I have the user flag in the gunicorn script set as my current user on my server and removed the user flag from the supervisor config file because I believe it was creating a conflict. Sorry I was unclear on this.

Answer (score 0):

In order to sort out the Import error 
(ImportError: No module named django.core.wsgi)

make sure that you have installed django in your virtualenv

To install django in the virtualenv enter the following commands:
 `cd <virtualenvdirectory>` , `source bin/activate` and
`pip install django`